# How do I find all the bits of a broken necklace?

Tags: home, retrieval

A necklace with lots of very small pearls broke, and they scattered all over the floor. I would like to find all of the individual pearls and reconstruct the necklace, but **is there a quicker way to do this than crawling around on my hands and knees?** The carpet is thick pile, so a dustpan and brush isn't really an option, and the pearls have bounced all the way around the room - under furniture and into crevices.

Comment: You might use tape. Form it into a round and start sticking it to the floor and then lifting up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with a vacuum cleaner. Use the hose, but put a thin piece of fabric (such as tights/pantyhose) over the end, fastened with a rubber band. Make sure you adjust the air inlet on the hose so that the engine isn't working too hard and doesn't overheat.

Use the covered hose to slowly work over the carpet, under furniture and in crevices to retrieve the pearls. They will be sucked up, but stay 'stuck' to the end of the hose, where you can grab them off, or just turn off the suction briefly while you hold it over a bowl to collect them.

Comment: Instead of using a tissue (which is likely to break on strong vacuum cleaners), use a pantyhose!

Answer (score 2):

In long fiber carpet, the easiest way is to vacuum thoroughly with an upright brush vacuum cleaner, with a new/empty bag/canister.

[image]

This gets it out of the long fiber carpet better than a simple suction. Also, some people have success with walking over the carpet in bare feet, covering all the area that way. However that is time consuming.